# VBA: Function works within subroutine, but not in sheet

Tags: vba, excel, do-loops

I've got this strange problem where my function works perfectly within a subroutine, but when I try to use it in a cell, it only returns the first value. The intended function is to work similarly to a vlookup, but to give me a comma seperated string with all the unique values.

I have narrowed it down to the `do` loop. I also tried rewriting the loop using a `while` loop, but got the same results.

```
Option Explicit

Function vconc(ByVal val_ As String, ByVal rng As Range, ByVal offset_ As Integer) As String
Dim s As String
Dim col_ As Variant
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

Set col_ = New Collection
' combination of the .find function and a collection to get a unique list of values
' works similar to a vlookup, but adds all the unique values to a collection
With rng
    Set c = .Find(val_, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        col_.Add c.Offset(0, offset_), CStr(c.Offset(0, offset_).value)

        Do
            ' adding a value with the same key to the collection gives us an error
            ' but I am interested in a list of unique values, so we simply ignore it
            On Error Resume Next
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            col_.Add c.Offset(0, offset_).value, CStr(c.Offset(0, offset_).value)

            ' this debug line only runs if the function is run within a subroutine
            Debug.Print c.Offset(0, offset_).value

        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

' concatenate the strings, seperate by ,
Dim item_ As Variant
For Each item_ In col_
    If s = "" Then
        s = item_
    Else
        s = s & ", " & item_
    End If
Next item_

vconc = s

End Function
```

**EDIT**: Following SJR's advice I was able to solve this by replacing the findnext line

```
Set c = .FindNext(c)
```

with this line

```
Set c = .Find(val_, after:=c, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Comment: For some reason FindNext doesn't work properly in UDFs. You have to use Find.

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you so much. Didn't think of googling that... Wonder why this has not been fixed yet...

Answer (score 0):

I can bet a virtual beer that the error is in the

```
With rng
```

write:

```
debug.print rng.address
debug.print rng.parent.name
```

In both the versions (the module and in the sheet) and check the results.

Comment: Good guess, but unfortunately I get the same range, $B:$B, and the same sheet name. Keep the suggestions coming, this thing is driving me nuts.